# Static (admin) files do not seem to be served correctly

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have problems with Django serving static files on the admin panel.

Calling `http://vbox.me/admin/` (where vbox.me is aliased to the VM's IP) results in a blank page without stylesheets.

Calling `http://vbox.me/static/admin/css/base.css` though, which is part of the stylesheets that *should* be loaded when opening `http://vbox.me/admin/`, brings up the correct file.

Here is some essential information:

- I recently started experimenting with Django.
- My current version of Django is 1.8.
- I'm running nginx (on Arch Linux within a VirtualBox on Windows 7) that passes every non-static file to uwsgi
- uwsgi and nginx run as service using systemd
- Running the Django development server standalone does not result in the given weird behavior.

**Nginx configuration file:**

```
# ...
http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream django {
        server unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }

    server {
        # ...
        location /static {
            # static directory of the django project
            alias /home/martin/projects/django_test/static;
        }

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass django;
            include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

**INI file for uwsgi:**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/martin/projects/django_test
wsgi-file=django_test/wsgi.py
chmod-socket=666
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
master=true
vacuum=true
```

**Important parts from `settings.py` within the Django project:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/martin/projects/django_test/static/'

# using vbox.me to make sure the browser does not make up some strange url.
STATIC_URL = 'http://vbox.me/static/'
```

I'm pretty much "left in the dark", I can only guess that I made some mistake in configuring uwsgi or Django, since nginx seems to server the static files perfectly (at least when explicitly requesting them...)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I will do a fresh setup of all the tools I use to deploy my app to make sure I made no mistakes. Additionally, I will be using virtualenv this time (which I haven't used previously). I'll let you know if that works!

Comment: Does the response on http://vbox.me/admin/ contain the correct link url to the stylesheets or do they miss in the rendered template?

Comment: All urls seem to be correct, I can open the stylesheets right from the source of the page

Comment: Have you inspected the page with a browser dev tool (like firebug) to see whether or not the browser tries to get the stylesheet URLs?

Comment: Both Firebux and Chrome Dev Tools tell the files have been loaded, same with the standalone Django dev server (fwiw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a fresh install of *everything* following [this tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html), everything works just fine now. Looks like I made some mistakes in configuration.

I also used Django 1.7 here, so Django 1.8 might have been the cause to my problems as well (though thats really unlikely)